# Can I deploy desktop application (application.exe) in java (netbeans)?

Tags: java, deployment, desktop-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Can I deploy desktop application (application.exe) in java (netbeans)?

I want to create setup of my Java application but I don't know how to do this.

How do I create `setup.exe` of java application that can run on any computer?

Comment: Use [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to deploy the app.  It works from a link, for Windows, ..OS X & *nix flavors that support a JRE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This answer still only has 4 upvotes in my link. I've given mine a long time ago but well...

Comment: *"can run on any computer"*  Note that only Windows will run a file with an extension of `.exe`.

Comment: @assylias  By 'This answer' DYM [the answer by TRA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/914948/418556)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes - I agree with you that it would deserve a better score...

Answer (score 1):

**1.** I am afraid that using NetBeans, you will **not be able to create a .exe file.**

**2.** But creating a `.exe` will **kill the very purpose of Java**, so an `Executable Jar` will be a good idea.

**3.** But still if you want to do it, then there are n number of 3rd tools out there.

**4.** `launch4j` is a good choice, **look the below link for details:**

```
   http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/
```

**Try this below site also, as you will get some good info abt this...**

```
   http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html
```

Comment: ok i have created .jar file but i want to ask can i use this .jar file in any pc as a desktop application like we use calculator(windows application c#)

Comment: When you want to launch this application, just Double click this Runnable Jar file... And please be careful.. I said Runnable(Executable) jar, NOT Simply jar

Answer (score 0):

Yes & no

Netbeans it self doesn't support generation of a native executable, however some of the executable wrappers do support Ant

I personally use [Exe4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html), but that's because it supports my needs, you will have to evaluate it yourself

Just as a side note, there is no way to generate a true, native executable for Java, all these types of products will only generate wrapper that will call Java on your behalf

As for creating a setup program. Again there are a number of choices.

The people who make Exe4J have a product available, but I personally have been using [IzPack](http://izpack.org/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a .exe file you can save the project in .jar and convert to exe after
here its http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/